# RDP to Host on Local home network whilst Client is connected to VPN, but also on Local home network

Tags: remote-desktop

Title explains what I want to do.

I'm using my **Work laptop** to connect to my **Personal laptop** via **RDP** (Remote Desktop).

They are both on my **Home network**.

Everything works until...

I connect my **Work laptop** to my **company VPN** (still working at home/on Home network).

When connected to company VPN, I can no longer RDP to my personal laptop.

Please tell me the easiest way to fix this so my RDP does not disconnect when using VPN.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When connected to company VPN, I can no longer RDP to my personal
> laptop.

It seems likely that your company VPN is not using Split Tunnel (either not available or not enabled).

No Split Tunnel means internet traffic is confined to inside the tunnel. Some companies want this setup for better company security. This is what prevents the RDP to the personal laptop.